# Script calls other script as .ps1 but not as a .exe using ps2exe

Tags: powershell, exe, start-process, ps1, ps2exe-gui

```
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString “Password+++” -AsPlainText -Force
$Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("Admin", $password)
$FileLocale = Split-Path -Parent -Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
Write-Output $FileLocale
$AntFile = "$FileLocale\StartApps.ps1"
Write-Output $AntFile
Start-Process PowerShell.exe -ArgumentList "-command &$AntFile -UserCredential $Cred"
```

Hi, that code works in .ps1, I call the other script, and he makes his job. But when I transform it in .exe with the help of ps2exe, he doesn't do his job anymore. As admin or not. It's not the first time I use that start-process, but it's the first time I use a variable as a target for the command. Do anyone know what go wrong between the ps1 and exe ?

Thanks

Comment: Where is this script getting the ```$MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition``` from ?
Also, You are hard coding your password ? (Not very secure)

Comment: For the password, yeah, not the best, but that script will pretty much be a one / two times use by me (Will work on the encryption if a need to use it more often). For the $MyInvocation, I only use it as a automatic variable for the script current directory... Which can explain why that don't work... But still don't know how to make it work...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While an executable compiled with [ps2exe](https://github.com/MScholtes/TechNet-Gallery/tree/master/PS2EXE-GUI) uses a `.ps1` file *as input*, *at runtime* no actual `.ps1` file is involved, which is why PowerShell's command-reflection variables cannot tell you anything about a running script *file*.

**When running an actual `.ps1` file**, you'd use the following [automatic variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables):

- [`$PSCommandPath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#pscommandpath) contains the the executing *script file*'s full file path.
- [`$PSScriptRoot`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#psscriptroot) contains the script file's full *directory* path (i.e. the full path of the directory in which the script file is located).

**In a ps2exe-compiled executable (`.exe`)**, where **these variables have no values**, you can **use the following instead**:

- [`[Environment]::GetCommandLineArgs()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Environment.GetCommandLineArgs)`[0]` contains the *executable file*'s  file name or path *as invoked* (when calling from `cmd.exe`) or as a *full* path (when calling from PowerShell).

  - Therefore, to ensure that a *full* path is always used, pass the result to [`Convert-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/convert-path)
- [`Split-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/split-path)  `(Convert-Path -LiteralPath ([Environment]::GetCommandLineArgs()[0]))` obtains the executable file's  full *directory* path.

---

Applied to your code - assuming that a separate `StartApp.ps1` file is present alongside your `.exe` file:<sup>[1]</sup>

```
$FileLocale = 
  if ($PSScriptRoot) { # running as .ps1 file
    $PSScriptRoot 
  } 
  else {               # running as .exe
    Split-Path (Convert-Path -LiteralPath ([Environment]::GetCommandLineArgs()[0]))
  }

$AntFile = Join-Path $FileLocale StartApps.ps1
```

---

<sup>[1] Note that at runtime *no* information is available about where the *original* `.ps1` file that served as *compile-time input* was originally located - only that file's *content* becomes part of the `.exe` file.</sup>