# Powershell script not working after converted to exe

Tags: powershell, ps2exe-gui

So, I have slowly, most thru google, created a powershell script to gather information from computers we need for work. A used laptop is booted with Hiren's BootCD PE Windows 11 installed on a USB Thumb drive.

The script prompt the user to enter a order, gathers date, computer model, CPU, Serial number, MAC and UUID and saves it to a text file.

The script works fine when I run it in Powershell, saves all information in the text file. But when I run the exe I created with PS2EXE so does only parts of the script work.

The script:

```
#Order:

    $order = Read-Host "Order?" 
    Echo Order: >> .\#files\file.txt
    $order >> .\#files\file.txt
    Echo ------------------------------------ >> .\#files\file.txt

#Date:

    Get-Date >> .\#files\file.txt
    Echo ------------------------------------ >> .\#files\file.txt

#Computer

    Get-CimInstance Win32_ComputerSystemProduct | Select Name >> .\#files\file.txt
    Echo ------------------------------------ >> .\#files\file.txt

#CPU

    Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_Processor | Select Name >> .\#files\file.txt
    Echo ------------------------------------ >> .\#files\file.txt

#SN:

    Get-CIMInstance win32_bios | format-list SerialNumber >> .\#files\file.txt
    Echo ------------------------------------ >> .\#files\file.txt

#MAC:

    Get-CimInstance win32_networkadapterconfiguration | select description, macaddress >> .\#files\file.txt
    Echo ------------------------------------ >> .\#files\file.txt

#UUID:
    
    (Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_ComputerSystemProduct).UUID >> .\#files\file.txt
    
    Echo ===================================================== >> .\#files\file.txt
```

When running the exe do I not get any error messages.

But when opening the text file so does only the #Order and #Date sections work as expected. The rest of the file is empty exept for the " Echo ----------------" lines

Comment: The `Exe` file unpacks your script and runs it at a different location, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71128507/1701026 (meaning that it uses a different current directory for e.g.:  `.\#files\file.txt`)

Comment: ah ok, but would that not mean that nothing in the script should work? Why would the #Order and #Date section work perfectly but the rest wont? Sorry, Im really new to Powershell so might be missing something simple.

Comment: What is the requirement to use a .exe file? Why not go straight to the author? https://github.com/MScholtes/PS2EXE/issues